# How to set application wide cultural information in a Winform Application

Tags: winforms, localization

I trying to set cultural information at the beginning of one of my winform application (VB .net). The code are:

```
Public Sub New()
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA")
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()


    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

However, datetime picker in the subsequent form shows date format of the type "dd-MM-yyyy". How can I set is right? What steps I am missing.

Comment: en-CA or en-US does not make any difference.

Comment: Try formatting numbers in greek and the commas and periods appear a different way round!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no application-wide setting for the default culture for new threads. The default culture of a thread is set by Windows when it is created.

Also check out this [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;889834&x=18&y=19), which is old but I believe still applies.  The DatePicker uses windows regional settings rather than currentCulture.

You can alter the settings for a DatePicker directly to make it display as you wish.

Something like:

```
DatePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DatePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
```

I think if I had many of these I may make my own class to inherit from DatePicker and set that in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I am making some mistake somewhere. Thanks for the link which provided clarity to my issue. Your idea of custom control seems to be very relevant, in appropriate cases.